# Pinging my ipv6 address is responded to by an unknown ipv4 address

Tags: networking, ipv6

I was recently doing some testing with IPv6 addresses to get a better understanding on how it all works. I checked my local "ipconfig" on windows and saw my my local v6 address, and also went to a "whatsmyip" style website to see what my "public" ipv6 address was.

Strangely I saw that the website was reading my connection from *::5 when my local machine is at *::4 (the star represents the same values on both scenarios).

I'm assuming that IPv4 was actually used to connect to the site as if it was an IPv6 connection I would have expected to see my personal ::4 and not my router's ::5 address.

Anyway, neither here nor there, as a test, I asked a colleague of mine working at a different location to try to ping my router and my personal PC's IPv6 addresses and in both cases the output from the (mac os) ping software was:

```
ping *::4
PING *::4 (143.244.220.150): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 143.244.220.150: icmp_seq=0 ttl=48 time=26.428 ms
64 bytes from 143.244.220.150: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=29.005 ms
64 bytes from 143.244.220.150: icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=27.205 ms
```

(Again, the * is just a place holder for the actual IP address values, omitted for obvious reasons).

The question I have, is what is 143.244.220.150 and why is it being pinged instead of the v6 address entered or my actual v4 address? For the record, that IP is not my network's public IPv4 address. Not only that, it's not even owned by my ISP and located geographically on the east coast whereas I am in the midwest.

Any Ideas?

Comment: If you're on ATT, this might be their automatic "DNS Error Assist" IP. See [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/homelab/comments/wkypc3/att_users_dont_forget_to_turn_off_dns_error_assist/).

Comment: When pinging an IP address, DNS is simply not in play. // Without know the exact command you used, it’s unfortunately not possible to tell what could be going on.

Comment: You do know how whatsmyip works, right? Why would you expect your own ip address to be visible? Also, OBVIOOUSLY (contrary to your statement) it is NOT using IPV6 to call the website but IPV4.

Comment: @TomTom How can you make these statements with the information given in the question?

Comment: @Rick: 1) What results do you get if you use `ping -6` instead? 2) What entries do you have in the `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file? 3) Are the `::4` and `::5` parts also completely made up, or are they literally the address suffixes of both your PC and your router?

Comment: @TomTom: First off, chill; second, isn't the whole _purpose_ of "whatsmyip" websites to show one's own IP address?

Comment: @TomTom lol yes I'm fully aware of how that site works and what Network Address Translation is. However, according to what I read, IPv6 is not like IPv4 and since there is essentially no limit to IPv6 addresses, the router DCHP supposidly assigns publicly routable addresses to internal devices and just "firewalls" them which I assume reduces the resource overhead not having to NAT for requests for those devices when using IPv6... I'm new with 6 though so that's just my understanding based on one thing I read.

Comment: @u1686_grawity - I'll have to try the -6 option anther time since it's after hours. These addresses are not in a hosts file, they are assigned via DHCP. See my comment above to "tomtom" to understand why I believe both the version that ends in ::4 is a live routable IP for my internal computer. the ::5 showed up on an external "what is my ipv6 address" type site, so I know that one at least is public.

Comment: @harrymc - The colleague was one an ATT fiber connection so that very well might be why they were seeing that...

Comment: @RickKukiela: Do you have a way of verifying that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2601:....::4 address appears to be a public IPv6 address that is assigned to my internal computer by my router, which was assigned the public IPv6 address of 2601:....::5 by by my ISP.

When I perform `ping -6 2601:....::4` (or the ::5) version from the ATT network externally I get request time out (as I expect to since my router is not set to respond to external pings). Additionally my router is going to firewall any IPv6 traffic to public IPv6 addresses inside the network that were not in response to a request originating from inside the network (similar to how NAT works).

My colleague must not have IPv6 enabled on their computer, so when I had asked them to ping me (as @harrymc said) they likely were getting ping responses from the some ATT service attempting to handle the request from that IPv4 address in different part of the country.

So, while I'm still not 100% for sure on why my colleague was getting those response, the assumption above is good enough for me, given than when I do the same ping from their same location with my IPv6 enabled computer, the routing appears correct and there is no rogue computers responding to the request.

Thanks to everyone that commented!